# avconv Fade Filter, Suitable output format error

Tags: video

I am trying to use the fade-in filter with ffmpeg, using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 "fade=in:0:30" output.mp4
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'fade=in:0:30'
```

I have checked the ffmpeg filters and the fade filter is installed correctly.

Please could someone let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Hi, here it is: ffmpeg version 0.8.4-4:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  6 2012 16:50:25 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    creation_time   : 2012-03-31 07:05:53
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.0

Comment: Duration: 00:00:10.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9485 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9402 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-03-31 07:05:53
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 199 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-03-31 07:05:53
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'fade=in:0:30'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the option `-filter:v`, which is followed by the filter name and parameters.  Without that, it will assume that `fade=in:0:30` is a file name.

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -filter:v fade=in:0:30 output.mp4
```

(Some older versions use `-vf` instead.)